# Правило в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте

1. У меня на сервере есть папка `templates`, которая находится в корневой директории
2. А так же есть контроллер с именем `templates`, url выглядит так... http://site.com/templates
3. При переходе по http://site.com/templates контроллер `template` не работает, так как он отображает папку `templates`.
4. Url работает так: после первого слэша - контроллер, после второго  модель, то есть http://site.com/templates/blog, где `templates` это контроллер, а `blog` это модель
5. В `htaccess` есть правило `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`, которое разбивает url по слэшу

Вопрос:
Подскажите правило для `.htaccess`, чтобы он подгружал контроллер, а не папку!?

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.stackoverflow.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stackoverflow.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes
Options -Includes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `rewriteCond` с `-d` по любому есть перед `rewriteRule`. приведите файл целиком в любом случае. да и по хорошему уберите из корня, все что там  не нужно. на кой вам папка шаблонов в вэб-руте

Comment: в принципе у вас в корне кроме `index.php` и папок `/js`, `/css`, `/img` особо и быть ничего не должно

Comment: зы: правило ваше не разбивает, конечно, по слэшу, а перенаправляет все что приходит на сервер в файл `index.php`, а там уже вы разбиваете по слэшу или как хотите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указанные правила работают только для несуществующих каталогов, файлов, и жестких ссылок.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Эта строчка `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` не дает запустить `index.php`.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/templates/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло!

Comment: Скиньте правила из `.htaccess` целиком.

Comment: Пожалуйста https://www.dropbox.com/s/5absmrusetk8s2r/htaccess.rar?dl=0

Comment: К сожалению не работает, все равно подключается папка templates